# What is the Windows 8 Metro Style Class Equivalent of Windos Phone 7 DeviceStatus Class?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, migration, microsoft-metro

I´m migrating an application from Windows Phone 7 to a Windows 8 Metro Style. 
On Windows Phone 7 I used DeviceStatus class to get some memory values:

- DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit
- DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage
- DeviceStatus.ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage
- DeviceStatus.DeviceTotalMemory

But this class doesn't exist for W8 Metro. Then, ¿How can I get this info?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can't retrieve those information referring to what is said in those topics

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/2011976e-6467-4dfb-af68-8d9c6239d2ac

and why it is impossible

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1ee76846-b419-46b1-9623-50a09306f4e4

Hope this help.